# non-word characters vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am attempting to use vim's regex engine to syntax highlight @ without any word characters adjacent to it, such as like this:

```
 The @ matches
 The@does not match.
```

I am either matching ALL @s or I am only ever matching @s with whitespace surrounding (Meaning those at the start of a line are not being matched.

It seems like vim does NOT actually adhere to regex standards in a very strict way, which is frustrating when writing syntax files.

Comment: Show us the regex you tried.

Comment: Vim's regex syntax inherits directly from ed's syntax and thus predates any attempt at creating a "standard".

Answer (score 3):

I feel regex in vim is really powerful, even though the syntax is a bit strange sometimes.

given following as example input:

```
@ foo
foo @ bar
foo @
foo@bar
```

this line: (leading by `/` (search) )

```
/\v(^| )\zs\@\ze($| )
```

matches the `@` in 1-3 line, but not the 4th line.

you could consider to use `\s` instead of `space` too.

Comment: Some explanations of some of vim's regex syntax being used here: `\v` turns on "very magic" which makes the regex syntax look similar to perl's regex syntax because it reduces the amount of escaping. `\zs` marks the start of the match and `\ze` marks the end of the match. For more help see `:h /\v`, `:h /\zs`, and `:h /\ze`